# Format MySQL timestamp to ics format

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp, icalendar

I am trying to convert some MySQL timestamps to the official .ics format. Unfortunately, I always get the output "`19700101T013334Z`".

MySQL format: `2014-09-29 18:00:00`

This is my PHP function, that should convert the dates accordingly:

```
function dateToCal($timestamp) {
    return date('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a Unix timestamp as the second parameter. You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert `$timestamp` to a Unix timestamp for you.

```
function dateToCal($timestamp) {
    return date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime($timestamp));
}
```

It might be easier, and better, if you converted that date to a Unix timestamp in your query using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already got an answer, but you can also do this in the database:

`SELECT FORMAT_DATE("2014-09-29 18:00:00", "%Y%m%dT%H%i%sZ");`

The Z at the end indicates UTC so if you're storing your dates using system time you'll want to convert that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert MySql's datetime to a Unix timestamp befor you can use it -

```
function dateToCal($timestamp) {
    date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($timestamp));
}
```

You really do not have to have the `\Z` in the function.